# Properly cleaning up memory after heavy OpenCV Operations

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin, memory-leaks

I am working on an android project that uses OpenCV for some face image related operations. Before I make a call to the OpenCV part of the application, my app’s memory usage is like ~50MB, during the call it can spike up to 600MB, but the issue I am experiencing, is that after the operation is complete the app’s memory usage averages at around 150MB adding 100MB to the pre-call memory usage, if the operation is repeated, 100MB will keep being added till there is an OOM, I have tried many ways to perform garbage collection in my code I call System.gc() after every operation.
I used the profiler and I can see that most of the memory was allocated from native code, does any how have any suggestions on how to properly clean up natively allocated memory. Please find a screenshot of my heap dump attached.

Any help at all would be deeply appreciated. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: What’s the OpenCV code that is giving you problems? Can you post a snippet?